# Ubuntu 16.04.2 on Intel NUC7i3, Bluetooth not working

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth, intel-nuc

Some days ago i bought a NUC7i3BNK and installed Ubuntu 16.04.02 with Kernel 4.8. Bluetooth does not work. 
My knowledge is not so deep, but I would say the driver is missing. Does anyone have a solution?

```
dmesg | grep Blue

[    3.000117] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[    3.000130] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    3.000132] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    3.000134] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    3.000139] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    3.013961] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    3.013962] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    3.013963] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    3.013964] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    3.013964] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    3.013965] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    3.013990] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    3.014001] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCM registered
[    3.014002] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    3.014002] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    3.061238] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    3.077988] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    3.077990] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.077990] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.077991] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.077992] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.077993] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.078594] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    3.357259] Bluetooth: hci0: Bootloader revision 0.0 build 26 week 38 2015
[    3.358365] Bluetooth: hci0: Device revision is 16
[    3.358366] Bluetooth: hci0: Secure boot is enabled
[    3.358367] Bluetooth: hci0: OTP lock is enabled
[    3.358368] Bluetooth: hci0: API lock is enabled
[    3.358368] Bluetooth: hci0: Debug lock is disabled
[    3.358370] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 1 week 10 2014
[    3.358394] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    3.486934] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.486935] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.486939] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized

lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

The Nano Tranceiver is  for my wireless keyboard and mouse. It makes no difference if I use another wireless keyboard:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 24ae:2010  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Answer (score 3):

The firmware for this BT device can be installed by updating `linux-firmware` package from `yakkety` repos.

It can be done by

```
sudo wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware_1.161.1_all.deb
```

This firmware contains the required `ibt-12-16.sfi` file.

Most likely the `xenial` version will be updated too in a while.

Answer (score 2):

Downloaded missing device firmware ibt-12-16.sfi, copied to /lib/firmware/intel, reboot, works perfect.

It is wonderful to hear music with my bluetooth connected speakers again.

I am not a Linux expert. Could someone explain to me whether this is the right way?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct solution. You installed the required firmware.

Comment: But it could be much better if you gave a download link for that file.