# Unable to connect Bluetooth devices to my laptop after updating Windows driver

Tags: 16.04, bluetooth

I have a dual boot system with Windows and Ubuntu. Previously my mouse and headphones were able to connect, but after I updated the driver on my windows side to deal with the disconnecting, I was no longer able to add devices on the Ubuntu side.

I currently only have Bluetooth manager. I tried to follow [these instructions on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2346879), but did not have any luck.

```
$ uname -r; lsusb; lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 net; rfkill list all; 
hciconfig -a; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
4.10.0-38-generic
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 03eb:8ab3 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b59c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 
[8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:0110]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:00:00:00:00:00  ACL MTU: 0:0  SCO MTU: 0:0
    DOWN 
    RX bytes:0 acl:0 sco:0 events:0 errors:0
    TX bytes:6 acl:0 sco:0 commands:2 errors:0
    Features: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
    Packet type: DM1 DH1 HV1 
    Link policy: 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 

[    0.178489] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    1.951585] [drm] GuC firmware load skipped
[    2.973757] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.973768] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.973770] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.973772] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.973775] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.982065] Bluetooth: HCI UART driver ver 2.3
[    2.982066] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol H4 registered
[    2.982067] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol BCSP registered
[    2.982067] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol LL registered
[    2.982068] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol ATH3K registered
[    2.982068] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Three-wire (H5) registered
[    2.982097] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Intel registered
[    2.982108] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Broadcom registered
[    2.982109] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol QCA registered
[    2.982109] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol AG6XX registered
[    2.982109] Bluetooth: HCI UART protocol Marvell registered
[    3.049076] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-26.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.049086] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-25.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.049092] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.049692] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.050693] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-8000C-22.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.057378] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 21.302800.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.032187] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout
[    5.032189] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[    7.048439] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0xfc05 tx timeout 
[    7.048440] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-110)
[    7.060257] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    7.060258] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    7.060260] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Maybe I need to try to uninstall the bluetooth from the windows side

Comment: Try a complete shutdown and then boot, make sure the fast startup in windows is disabled

Comment: it boots into ubuntu on start up

Comment: I've tired to follow the instructions but it did not make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

So I attempted to follow the instructions from [Ubuntu 16.04.2 on Intel NUC7i3, Bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887404/ubuntu-16-04-2-on-intel-nuc7i3-bluetooth-not-working) but it did not solve my issues. At least I know it didn't directly solve my issue

I ended up following these directions

[How to connect Bluetooth headphones to Laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867943/how-to-connect-bluetooth-headphones-to-laptop)

and used `bluetoothctl`to remove the device that is saved. Ran `scan on` then `pair <bluetooth mac address>` than `connect <bluetooth mac address>`

This worked for my mouse, but when i attempted to connect my JBL bluetooth headphones, it didn't work. So I'm not quite clear as to the reason of the issue.