# New Intel NUC - eth0 not showing from ifconfig

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

NUC model: NUC7i3BNK
OS: Lubuntu 14.04.2
Kernel: 3.13.0-53

---

contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

---

```
ifconfig -a:

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2115 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:151791 (151.7 KB)  TX bytes:151791 (151.7 KB)
```

---

```
lspci -v: 

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 5904 (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=10 <?>

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 5916 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at db000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at 90000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [ac] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [100] #1b
    Capabilities: [200] Address Translation Service (ATS)
    Capabilities: [300] #13

00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Device 1911
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at dc24f000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [dc] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [f0] PCI Advanced Features

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d2f (rev 21) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 136
    Memory at dc230000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d31 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at dc24e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d3a (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at dc24d000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d03 (rev 21) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 138
    Memory at dc248000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Memory at dc24c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at dc24b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d10 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=39, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: c4000000-da0fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000a0000000-00000000c1ffffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d15 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3a, subordinate=3a, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: dc100000-dc1fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d17 (rev f1) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=3b, subordinate=3b, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: dc000000-dc0fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Access Control Services
    Capabilities: [200] L1 PM Substates
    Capabilities: [220] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d4e (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0

00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 9d21 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at dc244000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]

00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 11
    Memory at dc240000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at dc220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 11
    Memory at dc24a000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 15d8 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 11
    Memory at dc200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features

3a:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 24fd (rev 78)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 9010
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 10
    Memory at dc100000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 28-c6-3f-ff-ff-ae-5c-31
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates

3b:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2068
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 137
    Memory at dc000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-01-00-4c-e0-00
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
```

I'm assuming that this is a driver issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve. The device cannot connect via wireless and cannot use Network Manager.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would use the latest version of Ubuntu with a new computer in order to get hardware drivers, that can recognize new hardware components. This was the case with my NUC6 when it was new. So I suggest that you try Ubuntu **17.10.1** and **'Bionic'** that is still being developed and will be released next month (April 2018) as Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. You can find the developing release via the iso testing tracker at http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a custom Lubuntu image. I would like to see if there are drivers to fix the issue before starting from scratch with a new OS.

Comment: I don't know how to add drivers like that. Let us hope that someone who knows will see your question and help you.

Answer (score 2):

The most hassle-free option will be to upgrade to Ubuntu 16.10 or later.  If this is not an option for you, the following has been purported to work, but I can't personally speak to how well it works.

You will need to manually install firmware for the NUC7i3BNK, since it's not included in the Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04 repositories.  A guide for doing so can be found here: [Ubuntu 16.04.2 on Intel NUC7i3, Bluetooth not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/887404/ubuntu-16-04-2-on-intel-nuc7i3-bluetooth-not-working)

Additionally, your kernel might not have drivers compiled in for that adapter.  To fix this, you would have to recompile your kernel from source, which is a non-trivial undertaking, but also not too difficult, once you get the hang of it.  (It's very CPU-intensive, and will take a few hours, most likely.)  When you do the "xconfig" step, you'll need to locate the driver for your card and choose the option to compile it into the kernel.  You can instead choose to compile the driver as a module, but then you'd have to load that module at boot by placing its name in /etc/modules.  Unfortunately, I don't know what the name of that specific driver is, so you'll need to figure that out.

Here is a guide for recompiling your kernel:
[What's a simple way to recompile the kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/163298/whats-a-simple-way-to-recompile-the-kernel)

Good luck!